# List size vs Set size doesn't match

Tags: java

When creating large lists I ran into something odd. I created sub lists, because the entire list was too large. But when checking the resulting sizes I found:

```
new ArrayList<>(rSet).size() != rSet.size();
```

Where rSet is a HashSet

When I stop eclipse and investigate, I see that rSet has 1000 items, whilst responding to .size() as having less (the number of `less` items fluctuates; sometimes the `rSet.size()` is higher than the values it actually contains). I cannot reproduce this in a separate test case; the code has too many layer to provide. But is filled from separate threads, which are ended by the time `size` is called.

I said I filled it from threads. I provide the `Set<> rSet` as parameter to all threads, and use the following method to add new items to the set:

```
public static void addSynchronized(final Set<?> c, final List<?> items) {
    c.addAll(items);
}
```

I must be doing something the code disagrees with... But what?

Comment: As other answers pointed out, the incongruence is probably caused by the set not retaining duplicate elements. If you wish to check if that's indeed the cause, you could iterate the lists beforehand and count how many duplicates there is. If the size of the set plus the duplicates matches the total size of the lists, you've found your answer. If that's not the case, you could consider posting an update to the question. Hope it helps. EDIT: As pointed in the comments to my answer, I completely misunderstood the question. Now that I understand it, IMHO the answer that Thomas wrote is the correct

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon The OP creates the list from the set values.

Comment: @Danielson From above method addSynchronized you are adding the items from list to set. But In the beginning of question you presented as the adding values to list from set. Which is correct one?

Comment: It sounds to me like a multithreading/race condition issue. Even if the threads filling the `HashSet` have finished, the Java memory model allows that the changes they have made are not yet written through to the thread creating the `ArrayList`.

Comment: “But is filled from separate threads…” Is that “threads” in plural? Filling an unsynchronized `HashSet`? That’s bound to go wrong. And in itself enough to explain that you get unexpected results later.

Comment: @OleV.V. yes, and that's why I (wanted to) call a synchronized method... Clearly I only named in synchronized and not used the keyword - that't not enough ;-) ...

Comment: Still I'm confused... I don't understand why (like described in question) the number of items in the set doesn't correspond with the result from `size()`, nor with the items that are in another `set` or `list` when copied. But perhaps that's just `magic`?

Comment: When you’re not synchronizing, *anything* can happen. Including what you have observed. I am in no way surprised.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is filled from separate threads

I think there's your problem. `HashSet` is not thread-safe. When writing to it from multiple threads at the same time, anything could happen.

To make it synchronized (from the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html)):

> ```
>  Set s = Collections.synchronizedSet(new HashSet(...));
> ```

Your `addSynchronized` method has a misleading name, because it's not `synchronized`. (Having an argument named `list` that's actually a `Set` is a bit confusing as well.)

Comment: I check that... I copied the method from another method that `had` synchronized as `keyword` (this is doesn't)... But still, there number of items seem to be correct, but `.size()` doesn't correspond - literally - with the number of items

Comment: Like I said, without correct synchronization, anything can happen. The internal state of your `HashSet` is clearly messed up.

Comment: I know... But overlooked that on this occation, and since I created another (really) synchronized method, for a `map`, I think I got sloppy :-( ... Thanks for pointing the keyword issues out :-)

Comment: Even that does not explain how "new ArrayList<>(rSet).size() != rSet.size();" can arise.

Comment: @ErwinSmout Yes, it can. I bet the `HashSet` caches its size, rather than iterating over its members each time you call `size()`. So if there is a read-increment-write operation going on to update the cached size, some changes to the cached size will be lost _even if_ all members were added to the hash table correctly. This is just one scenario which could explain the observed behaviour.

Comment: Yes I realized that when I read elsewhere "the HashSet gets corrupted", after I wrote that comment.  Basically all bets are off.  And I couldn't delete the comment anymore.